# how to display added comments in my orders

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2.

I want to show comments added by Admin User against a particular order placed.
I want to display this comments in table grid of My order section for customer login.

Answer (score 0):

**Step -1**

Go to the **\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\History.phtml** and override this file into your theme.

**Step -2**
Please **add the below code** into overridden **History.phtml**.

```
.................................................
<?php foreach ($_orders as $_order) : ?>
                    <?php 
        $history = [];
        foreach ($_order->getAllStatusHistory() as $orderComment) {
            $history[] = [
                'title' =>$orderComment->getStatusLabel(),
                'notified' =>$orderComment->getIsCustomerNotified(),
                'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($orderComment->getCreatedAt()),
                'comment' =>$orderComment->getComment()
            ];
        }

        foreach ($_order->getCreditmemosCollection() as $_memo) {
            $history[] = [
                'title' =>__('Credit memo #%1 created', $_memo->getIncrementId()),
                'notified' =>$_memo->getEmailSent(),
                'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_memo->getCreatedAt()),
                'comment' => ''
            ];

            foreach ($_memo->getCommentsCollection() as $_comment) {
                $history[] = [
                   'title' => __('Credit memo #%1 comment added', $_memo->getIncrementId()),
                    'notified' =>$_comment->getIsCustomerNotified(),
                    'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_comment->getCreatedAt()),
                    'comment' =>$_comment->getComment()
                ];
            }
        }

        foreach ($_order->getShipmentsCollection() as $_shipment) {
            $history[] = [
                'title' =>__('Shipment #%1 created', $_shipment->getIncrementId()),
                'notified' =>$_shipment->getEmailSent(),
                'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_shipment->getCreatedAt()),
                'comment' => ''
            ];

            foreach ($_shipment->getCommentsCollection() as $_comment) {
                $history[] = [
                    'title' =>__('Shipment #%1 comment added', $_shipment->getIncrementId()),
                    'notified' =>$_comment->getIsCustomerNotified(),
                    'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_comment->getCreatedAt()),
                    'comment' =>$_comment->getComment()
                ];
            }
        }

        foreach ($_order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_invoice) {
            $history[] = [
                'title' =>__('Invoice #%1 created', $_invoice->getIncrementId()),
                'notified' =>$_invoice->getEmailSent(),
                'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_invoice->getCreatedAt()),
                'comment' => ''
            ];

            foreach ($_invoice->getCommentsCollection() as $_comment) {
                $history[] = [
                    'title' =>__('Invoice #%1 comment added', $_invoice->getIncrementId()),
                    'notified' =>$_comment->getIsCustomerNotified(),
                    'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_comment->getCreatedAt()),
                    'comment' =>$_comment->getComment()
                ];
            }
        }

        foreach ($_order->getTracksCollection() as $_track) {
            $history[] = [
                'title' =>__('Tracking number %1 for %2 assigned', $_track->getNumber(), $_track->getTitle()),
                false,
                'created_at' =>$this->getOrderAdminDate($_track->getCreatedAt())
            ];
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($history);
        die();
        .....................................
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**You can get all the history comments.
you can implement based form this $history array.**

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**